# Postgres DateTimeField incorrect time

Tags: python, django, postgresql, timestamp

I have in my module DateTimeField:

```
class Pairs(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

and I insert data from python like this:

```
        timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(pair['timestamp'])
        tz_aware_datetetime = timestamp.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem'))
        pair_recored =Pairs(session=session_obj,timestamp=tz_aware_datetetime)
        pair_recored.save()
```

the timestamp from my code is:
`2019-08-15 08:50:07.795000+02:21`

but in my DB this field has different value:

`2019-08-15 09:29:07.795+03`

why there is this difference between these values?

Comment: What kind of timezone is `+02:21` supposed to be? `09:29:07 + 02:21 = 08:50:07+03`. PostgreSQL is correct.

Comment: sorry, the odd fraction made me confused, the problem isn't in Postgres as you said.

Comment: I've always wondered why `pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem')` returns stuff like that: `<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Jerusalem' LMT+2:21:00 STD>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `.replace()` method to set the timezone, use this instead:

```
pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem').localize(timestamp)
```

If you know the naive timestamp is the Asia/Jerusalem timezone, this is the correct way to make it timezone aware. It won't use these funny timezones like `LMT+2:21:00 STD` but `IDT+3:00:00 DST` instead (for a date in the DST timeframe).